# Can jmeter cli tools record a test script?

Tags: jmeter, command-line-interface

I am new to `jmeter`. Creating a simple script seems easy via browser actions [recording](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html). Can that be done [without](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) launching the jmeter IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start the JMeter proxy for recording the test and it is not possible to start the proxy through [available options](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui).

There is a number of ways available for building test plans including the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder.

[Ten different ways to build JMeter Test Plans](http://pragmatictestlabs.com/2021/10/20/jmeter-building-test-scripts/)

The recording feature can be used even for complex scripts. You will have to use/add JMeter components and configure them once the recording is done to achieve the desired user actions.

Answer (score 1):

As per [latest stable JMeter version 5.4.1](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) it's not possible to start [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) without starting JMeter GUI

If you cannot do this for any reason the options are in:

1. Use [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-continuous/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi?hl=en)
2. Use your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) to record your test request into a [.HAR file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAR_(file_format)), once done you can:

   - either use [online conversion tool](https://converter.blazemeter.com/) to convert .har file into a JMeter script
   - or manually create JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers by looking into requests details in the browser developer tools. If you cannot launch JMeter GUI at this stage as well you can consider using [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) automation framework which allows [creation of JMeter test plans using YAML syntax](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Building-Test-Plan-from-Config)